# how Index used in between query

Tags: mysql, indexing

How can get my index work when i query using Between command?

when i explain the query:

```
explain select * from table where Date between date1 and date2;
```

the return actual key be used is `NULL`, how to used my index in this case?

I have read some documentation from MYSQL, they said BTree index should be used here in order for > < or between query, however it doesnt work in my case.

Pls help

**EDIT**

```
explain  select * from table where Date between '2010-05-10 00:00:00' and '2010-06-10 00:00:00';
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+

| id | select_type | table  | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+

|  1 | SIMPLE      | table| ALL  | date_index    | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 109024 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: Do you *have* an index on the `Date` column? Also, `SELECT *` can force a full table scan.

Comment: yes i have Index on Date column and usign BTREE index, but it doesnt work

Comment: Is your date column an actual Date type ? How much are you restricting on in the where clause ? If your where is anyways spanning most of the data, there'll be little use of the index. Also, post the output of EXPLAIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing a datetime field with strings in a greater_than/less_than comparison. If you use a cast or function (like UNIX_TIMESTAMP()) and transform also the other dates to unixtimestamp, that would do the trick but will destroy the use of the index. Maybe a better solution would be to store the date as unix timestamp in the table and put an index on that. Then, you would only need to do:

```
select * 
from table 
where DateInUnixTimeStampFormat 
between UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date1) and UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date2)
```

OR

```
select * 
from table 
where DateInUnixTimeStampFormat 
> UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date1) and DateInUnixTimeStampFormat < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date2)
```

Comment: Using this query is the same. The actual index used in NULL

Comment: Yes it work if change to UnixTimeStamp. However i prefer using the datetime datatype, therefore i try using  STR_TO_DATE('(2010-3-31 16:24)', '(%Y-%c-%e %H:%i)') to convert it into datetime, but still not working, pls advise

Comment: I need to understand more about your use case. Do you always need to limit by day only (i saw you using time of 00:00:00)? or is it between any date and any time? are you using the results of this query to do another join? do all the results contain specific times , i mean, with minutes, seconds, etc or are at certain intervals like only every five minutes?

Answer (score -1):

you have to make your table lock type "**AllPages**";

```
alter table [table] lock allpages
go
```

after that, you have to create an index on that column (if you can create clustered index);

```
create nonclustered index ndx1 on [table] (col1, ...)
go
```

that run;

```
sp_recompile [table]
go
```

and finally look at your q-plan again. It should use an index.